# How to estimate a 90% interval with generated random samples from a posterior distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, confidence-interval

I generate 1,000 random samples from a posterior distribution which is $t_{19}(7.925, 0.14)$.

Now by using those 1000 samples, I'd like to estimate the 90% interval for $\mu$ (By the interval, I guess credible interval...).

Here are some information, you might find it helpful

(1).Interesting parameter is $\mu$.

(2).I have 20 randomly chosen samples $y_{1}=7, ...,y_{20}=5$

(3).Posterior distribution is $\mu|y\sim t_{19}(7.925, 0.14)$

(4).100(1-$\alpha$)% credible interval for $\mu$ is $\bar{y}\pm t_{n-1,\alpha/2}\,\large\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} $

I thought I could just calculate the 90% interval by using (4) but then I realized that I have to do it with the ones I generated.... and I guess I got stuck here.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Thank you.

Comment: You say "posterior distribution" which suggests a Bayesian context, which would make sense with a prior distribution for mean and variance of an underling normal distribution - but this is not stated.  You also say "I have 20 randomly chosen samples" but "I generate 1,000 random samples" which is confusing.  Perhaps you started with the $20$ values, found the sample mean and variance, then generated $1000$ from the corresponding $t$-distribution relocated and rescaled - not a Bayesian approach, but you could take the $50$th and $951$st of those and call that your $90\%$ interval for the mean

Comment: @Henry Each $Y_{i}$ comes from Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$ and $\mu$ is the only interesting parameter. By using independent Jeffreys priors, I  derived the posterior distribution $\mu|y$ which is a t distribtuon. I generated 1000 random samples from the t distribution  to find the 90% interval and I guess 5% percentile and 95% percentile would work.